# Is it a bad practice to use navigatorKey in flutter?

Tags: flutter

While I'm searching for a solution to navigate to some widget without context (my use case involves navigating to a widget onNotificationClick events). I found a solution to create a `GlobalKey<NavigatorState>()` and use it with `MaterialApps` `navigatorKey` property to navigate wherever I want.

It is working well for me, however recently I came across some comments in SO where it is said not to use this way because global keys are expensive but I couldn't find a complete answer to this question. So, is it really a bad practice, what can be an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter 1.22 introduced Navigator 2.0, a new declarative API that allows you to take full control of your navigation stack

1. Exposing the navigator’s page stack: You can now manage your pages
2. Backward-compatible with imperative API: You can use both imperative and declarative styles in the same app.
3. Handle operating system events: Works better with events like the Android system’s Back button.

Router(
routerDelegate: _appRouter,
backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
)),

4. Manage nested navigators: Gives you control over which navigator has
   priority.
5. Manage navigation state: Lets you parse routes and handles web URLs and
   deep linking

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about Navigator 2.0, I'll take a loot into it as an alternative. However I also wanted to know why navigatorKey is not preferred when used with onGenerateRoute.